# Relative Div Element not Registering with Absolutely Positioned Child

Tags: html, css, css-position

Alright, so, I'm still fairly new to CSS and HTML and have run into another problem. I couldn't seem to find my question already answered on here, but I hope to be redirected if someone finds out it has been asked and answered. Anyway, I'm using flex-box and attempting to horizontally align these three boxes within a wrapping div element. The three boxes themselves are relatively positioned, with a single absolutely positioned rectangle within each. So a div, surrounding three div boxes, surrounding a single rectangular div each.

[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIjF7.jpg)

I've managed to horizontally align them, but I've found an issue. The rectangular divs inside the three boxes are set up to "pull" out from the side of the boxes and form a band across with a tooltip over the front. I haven't even started work on the third box yet, because only the first box works how it's supposed to. The second box, for some reason, isn't functioning, and the absolute positioning of its band seems to be latching onto the header. So instead of pulling out from the side of its box, it is pulling out from the top side of the screen.

[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygD91.jpg)

When I delete the first box, the second box works fabulously. But both of them together, the first works, and the second blunders. Wrapping the faulty box in a second div prevents the problem. Also, borders don't show when I try to see where the apparently non-functioning div is, and letters typed within the div's HTML appear outside the image of the box. There is also a tiny dot below the element, or sometimes appearing beside it, that triggers the tooltip when hovered over.

What could possibly be the error? Are the two boxes somehow interacting and slipping each other up? Have I missed something? Help, please!

```css
#bodyWrap {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}


/* (1st) thumbnail begin */

.icon01 {
  height: 177px;
  width: 177px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.icon01 img {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.expThumb {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  top: 25%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.band {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 88px;
  top: 25%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #000000;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.icon01:hover .tooltip {
  width: 177px;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.icon01:hover .band {
  width: 178px;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.icon01:click .expThumb
/* (1st) thumbnail end */


/* (2nd) thumbnail begin */

.icon02 {
  height: 177px;
  width: 177px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.icon02 img {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}


/* insert expanded image here
. {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 opacity:0;
 visibility:hidden;
 z-index:6;
 -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
 -moz-transition: 0.2s;
 -o-transition: 0.2s;
 transition: 0.2s;
}
*/

.tooltip2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  top: 25%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 5;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.band2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 88px;
  top: 25%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #000000;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 4;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.icon02:hover .tooltip2 {
  width: 177px;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.icon02:hover .band2 {
  width: 178px;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.icon02:click .expThumb2
/* (2nd) thumbnail end */
```

```html
<div id="bodyWrap">


  <div class="icon01">
    <a href="#info">
      <img src="img/thumb.jpg" alt="box">
      <img class="expThumb" src="img/thumb2.png">
      <h2 class="tooltip">aTip</h2>
      <div class="band"></div>
    </a>
  </div>



  <div class="icon02">
    <a href="#info">
      <img src="img/thumb_announce.jpg" alt="box">
      <img class="" src="">
      <h2 class="tooltip2">aTip</h2>
      <div class="band2"></div>
    </a>
  </div>



  <div class="icon03">
    <a href="#info">
      <img src="img/thumb_announce.jpg" alt="box">
      <img class="" src="">
      <h2 class="tooltip3">aTip</h2>
      <div class="band3"></div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="info" class="active">
    <p>blahlbahlbahlbhalbhalbhalbhalbhalbhalbhalbhalah</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only `.icon01` is `position: relative;`. The other parents, `.icon02, .icon03` are statically positioned.

You can make those divs `relative` with the child combinator selector, or you could give them all a common class and target them that way, or you could just do `.icon01, .icon02, .icon03 { position: relative; }`. I'm using the child combinator selector here.

```css
#bodyWrap > div {
  position: relative;
}

#bodyWrap {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}


/* (1st) thumbnail begin */

.icon01 {
  height: 177px;
  width: 177px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.icon01 img {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.expThumb {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  top: 25%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.band {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 88px;
  top: 25%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #000000;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.icon01:hover .tooltip {
  width: 177px;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.icon01:hover .band {
  width: 178px;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.icon01:click .expThumb
/* (1st) thumbnail end */


/* (2nd) thumbnail begin */

.icon02 {
  height: 177px;
  width: 177px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.icon02 img {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}


/* insert expanded image here
. {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 opacity:0;
 visibility:hidden;
 z-index:6;
 -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
 -moz-transition: 0.2s;
 -o-transition: 0.2s;
 transition: 0.2s;
}
*/

.tooltip2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  top: 25%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 5;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.band2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 88px;
  top: 25%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #000000;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 4;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.icon02:hover .tooltip2 {
  width: 177px;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.icon02:hover .band2 {
  width: 178px;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.icon02:click .expThumb2
/* (2nd) thumbnail end */
```

```html
<div id="bodyWrap">


  <div class="icon01">
    <a href="#info">
      <img src="img/thumb.jpg" alt="box">
      <img class="expThumb" src="img/thumb2.png">
      <h2 class="tooltip">aTip</h2>
      <div class="band"></div>
    </a>
  </div>



  <div class="icon02">
    <a href="#info">
      <img src="img/thumb_announce.jpg" alt="box">
      <img class="" src="">
      <h2 class="tooltip2">aTip</h2>
      <div class="band2"></div>
    </a>
  </div>



  <div class="icon03">
    <a href="#info">
      <img src="img/thumb_announce.jpg" alt="box">
      <img class="" src="">
      <h2 class="tooltip3">aTip</h2>
      <div class="band3"></div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="info" class="active">
    <p>blahlbahlbahlbhalbhalbhalbhalbhalbhalbhalbhalah</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Using `.icon01, .icon02, .icon03 { position: relative;}` worked to put the tooltip and band in their places, but there's still a strange dot underneath the second box that, when hovered over, triggers the tooltip. Any idea what that could be?

Comment: @Pyrrly is that visible in your demo? I don't see a dot.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out (I think it was redundancy?)! Thank you! Combining the effects works better, and is a more organized way of doing things. :)

#edit I didn't see it in the demo either, and couldn't get it to reproduce. :/ So I think it had to do with some redundant text in the HTML and the CSS.

Comment: @Pyrrly sweet, no problem :)